# Screen is terminating, but the program is (apparently) running

Tags: c++, terminal

I keep having the following issue with `screen`, on a machine that I access by `ssh`. Once I am logged in and I have compiled my `g++` program, I run with `screen ./program.x` and I immediately get

```
screen is terminating
```

Although if I don;t use `screen`, the program actually runs well, without being terminated itself. Also, if I for example type `screen pico` this works fine, meaning that I can detach and reattach and `pico` is still there. Any ideas on what is happening? I don't have `root` privileges on this machine, which I access only remotely.

Comment: Perhaps your program does it's thing succesfully, and then terminates - then screen will also terminate - e.g. just as if you ran `screen ls` . See e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/362756/keep-gnu-screen-window-open-after-program-terminates

Comment: @nos The program is supposed to last for some minutes, it does not produce output in less than a second as it would be the case if what you say was true

Comment: True - unless your program forks() and places itself in the background, you need to debug it then ,e.g. run `screen /bin/sh -c "strace ./program.x ; sleep 60"` , or even `screen gdb ./program.x` and see what your program is up to. You can use the same approach to e.g. spawn a shell after your program is done to prevent screen from exiting,  run `screen /bin/sh -c "/program.x ; /bin/sh"`

Comment: So I inserted a couple of cout statements here and there and screen keeps terminating immediately. If I don't use screen, but rather just run the program with ./program.x , everything works fine, I have the desired output printed etc...

Comment: That's why I suggested you need to debug what's going on, either using the strace or gdb tool.